# Reference to parameters within an enum

Tags: rust, match, ownership

The code below gives the error "cannot move out of borrowed content". I know that there are already a lot of questions on here about this. I think that everyone using Rust finds themselves here at one point, trying to figure out exactly what is going on with ownership. I think I know what's going on here and how to fix it, I just don't know how to use a reference in this particular case. If there is a more idiomatic way to accomplish what I am trying, please let me know in the comments.

I can see where I'm trying to take ownership, but I'm unsure how to use a reference instead.

Let's look at a somewhat minimal example:

```
/* I define two shape structs. The main point here is that they
 are not default copyable, unlike most primitive types */

struct Circle {
   center_x: f64,
   center_y: f64,
   r: f64,
}

struct Square {
    center_x: f64,
    center_y: f64,
    length: f64,
}

/* this enum will be a container for shapes because we don't know
   which shape we might need. */

enum Shape {
    // these are scoped differently, so it's okay.
    Circle(Circle),
    Square(Square),
}

/* I'm making cookies, each cookie has a shape */
struct Cookie {
    shape: Shape,
}

/* All of the above was setup, here is where we find errors */   

impl Cookie {

    /* checks if two cookies have the same radius. squares -> false */

    fn has_same_radius(&self, other_cookie: &Cookie) -> bool {
    // fn has_same_radius(self, other_cookie: Cookie) -> bool {

    /* swapping the above two lines will remedy the error, 
       but I don't want this function to take ownership of either */

        match self.shape {

            /* As soon as I declare c1, I'm taking ownership of self.shape
               and therefore self as well. This is in spite of the fact
               that I never plan to alter anything. 
               How can I simply use a reference to c1> */

            Shape::Circle(c1) =>  match other_cookie.shape {

                /* same thing here with c2 */
                Shape::Circle(c2) => {
                    if c2.r == c1.r {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                Shape::Square(_) => return false,

            },
            Shape::Square(_) => return false,
        }
        return false;

    }

}
```

When I match on the `Shape` enum, I only want to reference the parameter encapsulated in `Shape`, but since I am not using a reference, I am trying to take ownership of the entire Cookie struct.

Comment: Please completely read the error messages that the compiler provides. The message says "help: to prevent the move, use `ref c1` or `ref mut c1` to capture value by reference". If you find the error messages too confusing, then [file an issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust) describing what better phrasing or presentation of the errors would have made it clearer.

Comment: @Shepmaster I spent about 2 hours trying to figure this out. I knew it had to be something simple, but when I read `ref c1`, I, being newish to Rust, Immediately tried `&c1`. Now that it's been mentioned, I do remember reading about `ref` in the documentation when I first went through it, but I recall not seeing any context where it was different from `&` and promptly put it out of mind. This is one of those cases where I really didn't even know the right question to ask. Now that its been explained, I'm kicking myself because the error message was perfectly helpful, I was just being dumb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change

```
....
Shape::Circle(c1) => ...
....
Shape::Circle(c2) => ...
....
```

to

```
....
Shape::Circle(ref c1) => ...
....
Shape::Circle(ref c2) => ...
....
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=7bdd77b6d46f05c71c3f76cd247d8381&version=stable&backtrace=0)

`let ref x = y;` is basically the pattern matching version of `let x = &y;`.

Comment: @Liam do you feel that this or the other answers your question? If so, could you accept one of the answer?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed by [WiSaGan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37268185/5189607), you must use `ref` pattern to create a reference to the contained value. You can also simplify the code matching against the two shapes simultaneously:

```
impl Cookie {
    fn has_same_radius(&self, other: &Cookie) -> bool {
        match (&self.shape, &other.shape) {
            (&Shape::Circle(ref c1), &Shape::Circle(ref c2))  => c1.r == c2.r,
            _ => false,
        }
    }
}
```